# Questions regarding measurement of a qubit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, observables, quantum-measurements

I am trying to understand the basic concept of observable and state. Say that we have a state $|\psi>=|0>$ which is $(1\ \  \ 0)^T$, we have an observable $\sigma_x=
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$.I would like to know what do I get if I measure $\sigma_{x}$ on this state? Should we simply apply the observable on the state?

Comment: Are you asking what happens when you measure once in a single shot, or how you would calculate an expectation value? These are two different things.

Comment: I am actually confused about the former, but also want to know what happens mathmatically for the former situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you measure an observable $A$ in a state $|\psi\rangle$ the expectation value of the observable is $\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle$. The possible measurement outcomes are the eigenvalues of the observable $a_1,a_2\dots$ and the expectation value is $\sum_i a_ip_i$ where $p_i$ is the probability of the $i$th outcome. When you do the measurement you will see the value $a_i$ with probability $p_i$.

You will need to calculate the eigenvalues of $\sigma_x$. Then you could write down $\sigma_x$ in terms of $|i\rangle\langle j|$ operators, calculate the expectation value and work out the probabilities from that. Or you can write down $|\psi\rangle$ in terms of the eigenvectors of $\sigma_x$ and the square modulus of the amplitude of each state gives you the probability of each state and so the probability of each of the possible values.

You can find more on how to do this in any decent textbook, such as "Quantum computation and quantum information" by Nielsen and Chuang.